# document.body.insertBefore on iOs Safari not working

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I'm creating an embedding system, however I'm having problems with Safari on iOS. I retrieve my HTML code through an AJAX request, which works except for on Safari on iOS, which was the only browser that did not embed the code.

Code used to insert element into the page:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.setAttribute('id', 'chat-robbu');
el.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');
el.innerHTML = data.html; // data.html is part of an object received through an AJAX request
document.body.insertBefore(el, document.body.children[0]);
```

You can see the code working here: https://chatrobbu.rilo.com.br

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the issue. Your code and the website to which you linked seem to be working exactly as intended in Safari on my iPhone (running iOS 11.4.1).

Comment: @aaplmath On my iphone the code just does not execute

Comment: What version of iOS are you running?

Comment: @aaplmath 11.4.1, I'm noticing navigation problems on many websites, is the problem with my device?

Comment: Try checking Settings > Safari > Advanced and make sure JavaScript is enabled.

Comment: For some reason my JavaScript was disabled? I have no idea how this happened...

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate my comment, since it was, in fact, the underlying issue: Ensure that JavaScript is enabled under `Settings` > `Safari` > `Advanced`, or the code won't execute.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.